# Angular Nativescript absolute in gridlayout not working

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am new with `nativescript` and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with `grid`.

As I understood `AbsoluteLayout` is same as "absolute" in web, and `GridLayout` is like flex with rows and cols. So I am trying to make top header absolute on top of everything :

```
<GridLayout  rows="auto, *" >
        <AbsoluteLayout >

        <GridLayout #homeHeader backgroundColor="#F6F6F5"    rows="auto,auto,*" >


                <custom-action-bar  #title [row]="0" title="List"></custom-action-bar>


                <search  [row]="1" (submit)="onSearch($event)" (clear)="onClear()" ></search>




        </GridLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <StackLayout row="1">
    <ListView>
    <GridLayout>
    Here is the content I scroll which is in GridLayout.
    </GridLayout>

    </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

**Result :**

Normal grid, no absolute layout, header acts like StackLayout pushing away another StackLayout.

**Expected behavior :**

My header would become absolute on top of everything.

**Question :**

How to make my header always be on top - absolute so I could make translate animations on him ? (In future I want that onscroll header hides with translate animation)

Comment: I don't think you need a AbsoluteLayout for a fixed header, just a GridLayout should be enough. Not sure why you have ListView in the middle, if you show us some mockup or wireframe to demonstrate what exactly you are looking for, it's easy to give you some directions. Learn more about layouts at [nslayouts](https://www.nslayouts.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this link, it really helps a lot.